# dragging in libgdx flickers

Tags: java, libgdx

I want to drag an `Actor` around with the `Mouse` in `LibGDX`.
My code:

```
// overrides in the ClickListener
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y,
                int pointer, int button) {
            touching = true;
            prevTouchPosition = new Vector2(x, y);
            return super.touchDown(event, x, y, pointer, button);
        }

        @Override
        public void touchDragged(InputEvent event, float x, float y,
                int pointer) {
            dragging = true;
            lastTouchPosition = new Vector2(x, y);
            super.touchDragged(event, x, y, pointer);
        }

        @Override
        public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y,
                int pointer, int button) {
            touching = false;
            super.touchUp(event, x, y, pointer, button);
        }

// the update method
    @Override
    public void act(float delta) {
        super.act(delta);
        if(dragging){
            Vector2 diff = new Vector2(lastTouchPosition).sub(prevTouchPosition);
            translate(diff.x, diff.y);
            prevTouchPosition = new Vector2(lastTouchPosition);
            dragging = false;
        }

    }
```

The more I move the `Actor` around the worse it gets.
The idea is to keep the last two `Mouse` positions and use the difference between them to update the position of the `Actor`.

Comment: Can you provide more details than "the worse it gets"?  As to what the problem is?  Stop moving?  Moves too much?  Gets real slow?

Comment: I'll try: so I start with an image in bottom left corner and I drag it to the upper right corner. In this scenario the mouse will start to lead the image and it will reach the upper right corner way before the image will. Also when dragging the image's position doesn't always change gradually and goes back a bit sometimes. In another scenario where I grab the image and spin it around, I can clearly see two images that are spaced relatively wide apart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything incremental like this is going to suffer from roundoff errors. Moreover, I think you don't need to update `prevTouchPosition` every frame; in the absence of roundoff errors, it should not be changing. Note that your code only works if the object is not rotated or scaled.

A more robust drag algorithm works as follows:

- upon touch down, touch point L in object-local coordinates:

  - G := L
- upon touch move, touch point L in object-local coordinates:

  - setPosition(toGlobal(L) - toGlobal(G) + getPosition())

Note that we never update G during the drag operation; it is used to remember the point on the object where it was "grabbed", and we continuously align the object so that this point is under the current touch. Here, toGlobal(L) - toGlobal(G) gives you the "delta" vector in global coordinates, which we add to the current position.

Note that I'm assuming there's no object hierarchy, so the current position is itself in global coordinates. Otherwise you'll need to take the parent's transform into account as well.

Comment: Thanks for the solid answer. I have a small problem though. The dragging works fine with only a rotation or with only a scaling. But when I combine a rotation and scaling with a large difference between xScaling and yScaling, the Actor that I drag around shakes around the mouse cursor a bit. The effect is not visible with xScale=yScale. But is more noticeable when abs(xScale-yScale) increases. When I set xScale=1 and yScale=2 the effect is really annoying. By shaking around mouse cursor I mean that the image that I'm dragging temporarily has different coordinates (other than the mouse cursor).

Comment: Best if you post a new question and show us the code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21801439/dragging-an-actor-shakes-around-mouse-pointer